# Unbind keypress handler for specific combination only

Tags: jquery

I have 2 keydown handlers:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 75) {
       // handler1 strategy
   } else if (e.keyCode == 78) {
       // handler2 strategy
   }

});
```

How can I unbind one handler without affecting all the other keydown handlers?

updated.

Comment: Why do you have two handlers for keydown?

Comment: Because I need to have custom handlers for different actions :) Do you recommend to make some smarter common handler?

Comment: Why don't you write a single handler and in that handle the different actions?

Comment: 2rahul: updated. But the question is how can I unbind one "handler strategy" without affection other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a plugin that maintains a map of key combinations, and associated functions. Whenever it sees a keydown event, it calls each matching function. Removal of an existing handler will be easy too.